# Using *ngFor rendering Angular html tags

Tags: angular

I wanted to know if there is a way to use ngFor for rendering components, like in the codes in [this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/tabs/)

summarizing, I wanted to do something like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of tabs" class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div
    class="tab-pane fade show active"
    [id]="item.tab"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="{{ item.tab }}-tab"
  >
    <app-{{item.tab}}></app-{{item.tab}}>
  </div>
</div>
```

assuming I have the components created and the tabs variable as such:

```js
 tabs = [
        { title: "Impresoras", tab: "printers" },
        { title: "Mapa de Ataques", tab: "attacks" },
        { title: "Alerta de Vuelos", tab: "flights" }
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (based on your code sample) that you have custom components for each tab (e.g. `<app-printers>`, `<app-attacks>`, `<app-flights>`), you could use an `*ngSwitch` structural directive to accomplish your goal:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of tabs" class="tab-content" id="myTabContent" [ngSwitch]="item.tab">
  <div
    class="tab-pane fade show active"
    [id]="item.tab"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="{{ item.tab }}-tab"
  >
    <app-printers *ngSwitchCase="printers"></app-printers>
    <app-attacks *ngSwitchCase="attacks"></app-attacks>
    <app-flights *ngSwitchCase="flights"></app-flights>
  </div>
</div>
```

Certainly, you could also do this using `*ngIf`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of tabs" class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div
    class="tab-pane fade show active"
    [id]="item.tab"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="{{ item.tab }}-tab"
  >
    <app-printers *ngIf="item.tab === 'printers'"></app-printers>
    <app-attacks *ngIf=item.tab === 'attacks'"></app-attacks>
    <app-flights *ngIf="item.tab === 'flights'"></app-flights>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The ngFor statment is correct but the problem here is the  tag,

```
<app-{{item.tab}}></app-{{item.tab}}>
```

app item tap could be a generic component with an Input decorator 
like:

```
<app-generic-tap [itemTap]="item.tap"><app-generic-tap>
```

Take a look to the Angular documentation especially in the @Input and @Output Decorators.